# Does linux store time zone offset information with each file?

Tags: linux, timezone, ls, timezone-offset

I am displaying the full file metadata for two files `sample1.avi` and `sample2.avi` that have each been created in different time zones:

```
$ ls -l --full-time sample1.avi sample2.avi
-rw-r----- 1 dzhelil dzhelil 9753270 2007-01-21 08:02:54.000000000 +0100 sample1.avi
-rw-r----- 1 dzhelil dzhelil 9753270 2019-07-24 14:37:14.383564894 +0200 sample2.avi
```

In addition to the actual time, there is a field of `+0100` and `+0200` for the files. What does that field mean? Does each file contain a reference to the time zone as well? Is there any way to change the timezone for all files to be the one of the current location rather than the one where they were created?

Comment: Hi.  This question is not [on-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Please ask on either [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/).  Thanks.